# What does "Whole Page" zoom option in SSRS do?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a web based SSRS report and it displays perfectly. By default it zooms to "Whole Page" but when I change the percentage to something else -say- 25%, it changes but when I return it to "Whole Page", it stays the same.

QA is giving me a hard time so I was just wondering what the "Whole Page" option was for?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I replicated your issue in Report Manager. These zoom values *do* take effect in the Windows Forms Report Viewer - whether that's enough for your QA team, who knows? As to why it's like this, it could just be that they apply in some places (i.e. Windows Forms) and not others (i.e. Report Manager) and SSRS always displays all zoom levels potentially available, even if some aren't applicable in that particular display medium. Seems like poor user experience but maybe it's just by design, or even a bug in our respective versions.

Comment: You won't generally see this in Report Manager actually.  Access your portal via the ReportServer endpoint (http://yourssrsurl/ReportServer/), browse to a report  (choose one that tends to be very tall, that you'd normally need to scroll down to see), and run it.  Now, add "&rc:Zoom=Whole%20Page" to the end of your URL, hit enter, and run the report again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about the various SSRS device settings [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397%28v=sql.90%29).  The "Zoom" option is, I believe, only available on HTML rendering - it won't carry over to your typical export formats.

Zoom can be set to either a % value, or the string values "Whole Page" and "Page Width".  "Whole page".  The string values are pretty self-explanatory.

"Page Width" will scale your report horizontally so that it fits perfectly within with pages horizontal margins.  There should be no horizontal scrolling necessary to view the report, though vertical scrolling will still be necessary.

"Whole Page" will attempt to zoom the report to such a level that the entire page is displayed at once in your report viewing frame - whether than means scaling it up or down.

Try testing this behavior with reports that contain objects besides just tables - tables are somewhat flexible already, and can be hard to identify scaling behavior with.  Also, try changing your browser window size between executions - shrinking your browser to like 1/4th of your screen and running a report with a "Whole Page" zoom level should results in an almost unreadable report.